# CSS ContentEditable Span: Ugly Border

Tags: html, css

I have to make some text editable to form an Email. To indicate where text may be changed, I want to give a border around editable passages.
Sadly, it looks pretty ugly with:

```
outline: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
```

If the editable span contains a line break (`border` looks even worse!).

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5qdA/1/ for reference. Try to add a double line break and some text. Especially line breaks will result in very ugly vertical borders.

Another problem is (only tested on firefox), that if you add a line break at the end, you can't remove it (it creates a new break with `type="_moz"`, which won't get removed...)

Is there some way to work around this ?

ps: I have jQuery / jQuery-UI at hand, but wouldn't like to use plugins...

Comment: Maybe some `padding`, `margin` and more `line-height`makes it look better.

Comment: Drop the outline altogether and combine a light background with a dashed border on the bottom? http://jsfiddle.net/Q5qdA/6/

Comment: hmm...why didn't i come to the idea using a background? ...i'll do it that way (probably looks better than a border anyways :) )

Answer (score 0):

its hard to get your problem, because its not easy to see, what you wish.

But maybe its better to get one outline for one span :

Here's my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5qdA/7/

```
p {
width:210px
}
```

(for example)
with a width you can solve this.

Comment: hmm my english might not be the best....but try it out yourself. make the span `contenteditable="true"` and when you edit it, press enter once or twice. see the results...